# Particpial phrases containing different nouns

Tags: commas, subordinate-clauses, participial-phrases

is it possible to use participial prepositions in the following sense, or am I creating a dangling modifier. Moreover, is the punctuation correct?

Considering his broken leg, Peter was not able to walk anymore.

Peter was not able to walk anymore considering his broken leg.

Understanding Einstein's statements is neccessary, since Peter wants to graduate in Physics in order to get a good job.

Since Peter wants to graduate in Physics understanding Einstein's statements is neccessary, in order to get a good job.

Can participial preposition be used as subordinating conjunctions?
Maybe a native could help me out here. Thanks!

Comment: My first reaction to your 3rd and 4th sentences is: what does ***me*** (or the community) understanding Einstein have to do with ***Peter*** getting a good job?

Comment: I'm asking about the structure, not the content in specific...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the structure in general, but there is definitely something wrong with what you think the structure means.

Comment: I have no problem understanding **Peter** as being the logical subject of "understanding Einstein's statements".  The term "participial prepositions" is confusing, since there are no such things, and "understanding" in the examples is neither a participle nor a preposition.

Answer (score 0):

Your your first rephrasing would be correct if you had used commas thus:

Peter was not able to walk anymore, considering his broken leg".

However, this would be better rephrased as "... On account of", "...because of" or "...due to" "his broken leg".

"considering " is not ungrammatical; it is simply less idiomatic (at least in AmE).

As for your rephrasing of your second example: it preserves the intention better to put it this way:

Since Peter wants to graduate in Physics to get a good job, understanding Einstein's statements is necessary.

Note that "in order" is universally superfluous in this sense. "in order" is only necessary when describing a sequence: "they placed the dominoes in order according to the lowest number of pips on each."

Comment: It's not hair-splitting. In your first example, Peter is ***not*** the one considering his broken leg, and he is the only one mentioned in the sentence. The second example would be much better phrased: *"Since Peter wants to graduate in Physics, he needs to understand Einstein's statements to get a good job."*

Comment: I guess you misinterpreted the prodvided example."Since Peter wants to graduate in Physics, he needs to understand Einstein's statements to get a good job." This sentence mixes up the intention. He want to graduate in physics to get a good job. But in order to graduate he needs to understand Einstein's statements. 
So first, Einstein; then graduate; then good job... Or maybe I'm confused because of the punctuation, but that was what I wanted to ask.
In the first example, would that be a dangling modifier?

Comment: I rephrased my answer.